# Deploying application.yml on tomcat does not work

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller

I'm trying to deploy my spring mvc project to my tomcat server. But the settings in `resources/application.yml` don't work on tomcat server.

In my `IntelliJ Tomcat Server`, it does.

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>https://example.com/manager/text</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

application.yml in resources/:

```
server:
 servlet:
  contextPath: /
  session:
   timeout: 3000
```

The site is available on my project-name instead of / (On tomcat Server there is no site under /)
And the session-lifetime is `1800` instead of `3000`

Do anyone have an idea what's the problem?

Comment: Do you using the spring boot? if you use the spring boot this link https://www.programmergate.com/deploy-spring-boot-application-external-tomcat/ can help you to deploy spring boot to external tomcat. After that, you can run maven tomcat plugin again to deploy your application.

Comment: The `server` properties are only used when using an embedded server not when deploying to an external tomcat.

Comment: Yes we couldn't configure the tomcat with properties file. It is unnecessary to deploy to external servlet container.